# sympy использование формулы

Tags: python, sympy

Ввожу формулу через sympy с помощью:  `expr = expr.evalf(subs={x: xmas[0], a: amas[0]})`  , но затем хочу использовать ее в цикле:

```
for i in range(len(amas)):
    for i1 in range(len(xmas)):
        expr = expr.evalf(subs={x: xmas[i1], a: amas[i]})
        print(expr)
```

Проблема в том, что формула считается только для первых чисел массива, как можно сделать, чтобы формула, считанная единажды могла быть использована большое количество раз?

Comment: Просто не перезаписывайте старое значение expr, а записывайте результат в новую переменную.

Comment: Не работает, проблема в том, что команда ```expr.evalf(subs={x: xmas[i1], a: amas[i]})``` единажды инициализирует формулу

Comment: `проблема в том, что команда expr.evalf(subs={x: xmas[i1], a: amas[i]}) единажды инициализирует формулу` - вообще-то нет, `evalf` никак не изменяет `expr`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QykES.png Вы просто сами `expr` перезаписываете новым значением.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZgLDVup
Я пробовал менять перменную, есть идея, почему он упорно не хочет считывать числа с массивов?

Comment: Добавьте полный код в сам вопрос

Comment: А вообще вижу, у вас выше цикла зачем строка `expr = expr.evalf(subs={x: xmas[0], a: amas[0]})` ?

Comment: Действительно, голова кругом от этих библиотек, не заметил, спасибо, теперь нормально